# Is this reinterpret_cast OK to do

Tags: c++, c++builder, reinterpret-cast

I am a EE, not a code expert, so please bear with me here.

I am using Embarcadero C++ Builder (XE3).

I have an FFT algorithm which does a fair number of operations on complex numbers. I found out that if I bypass Embarcadero's complex math library, and do all the calculations in my own code, my FFT will run about 4.5 times faster. The 4 operations shown here all require an inordinate amount of time.

```
#include <dinkumware\complex>
#define ComplexD std::complex<double>
ComplexD X, Y, Z, FFTInput[1024];
double x, y;
Z = X * Y; 
x = X.real();
y = X.imag();
Z = ComplexD(x,y);
```

Replacing the multiplication with my own cross multiply cut my execution times in half. My concern however is with the way I am accessing the real and imaginary parts of the input array. I am doing this:

```
double *Input;
Input = reinterpret_cast<double *>(FFTInput);
// Then these statements are equivalent.
x = FFTInput[n].real();
y = FFTInput[n].imag();
x = Input[2*n];
y = Input[2*n+1];
```

Doing this cut my execution times in half again, but I don't know if this reinterpret_cast is a wise thing to do. I could change the input array to two doubles instead of a complex, but I am using this FFT in numerous programs and don't want to rewrite everything.

Is this reinterpret_cast OK, or will I have memory problems? Also, is there a way to get the Embarcadero complex math functions to run faster? And finally, although its not terribly important to me, is this reinterpret_cast portable?

Comment: You say you are EE, what is it?

Comment: Does it work? Are the results correct? You seem very concerned about speed, but speed means nothing without correctness.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is never totally OK, it's a question of whether it's OK on your machine, with your compiler. It does look like you will be able to get away with it. But I would investigate changing compilers instead

Comment: I don't see anything terribly wrong if FFInput is just two doubles, compiler is unlikely to add padding here.

Comment: Without seeing the actual code that you benchmarked, it's impossible to say what's an appropriate approach. But, first of all, did you compile with optimizations enabled? If not, the timings don't mean anything.

Comment: @piokuc Electrical Engineer I imagine.

Comment: The code works fine, and the FFTInput is 2 doubles. I tried turning on the fastest code optimizer, and to use register variables. That made the code about 10% faster.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but a strong hint: `#define ComplexD std::complex<double>` is **BAD CODE**. Do this instead: `typedef std::complex<double> ComplexD;`

Comment: Re: typedef std::complex<double> ComplexD; I can do that.

Answer (score 5):

This is allowed. Whilst this isn't a standard quote, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) has this to say:

> For any pointer to an element of an array of complex numbers `p` and any
>   valid array index `i`, `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i]` is the real part of
>   the complex number `p[i]`, and `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i + 1]` is the
>   imaginary part of the complex number `p[i]`.

I will look for the quote from the actual standard soon.

Comment: [complex.numbers]/4. It is *almost* a Standard quote ;)

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) it says at the bottom of the page:

> For any complex number z, **`reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[0]`** is the real part of z and **`reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[1]`** is the imaginary part of z.
>
> For any pointer to an element of an array of complex numbers p and any valid array index i, **`reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i]`** is the real part of the complex number p[i], and **`reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i + 1]`** is the imaginary part of the complex number p[i]. (Since C++11)
>
> These requirements essentially limit implementation of each of the three specializations of std::complex to declaring two and only two non-static data members, of type value_type, with the same member access, which hold the real and the imaginary components, respectively.

So what you are doing is guaranteed to work in C++11, but not before that.  It may still work with your library's implementation, but you need to check that your library's implementation does not define any more non-static data members as per the third paragraph.

Comment: These are almost exact quotes from 26.4/p4, so this is officially sanctioned.

Comment: Is this what you are referring to? typedef struct _C_double_complex{double _Val[2]; } _C_double_complex;   /* double complex */

Comment: Wow, I had no idea the standard sanctioned this.

Comment: @user5108_Dan No, you're looking for a C++ `template <class T> class complex;` or somesuch, that is a C struct you have.

Comment: @EricNiebler I suspected that barring bizarre implementations it should be possible, but I didn't know it was legal either